# How do you reserve a pygame.mixer Channel in pygame?

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mixer

How does reserving channels work? Can I reserve specific channels or are they picked randomly? There is no clear documentation on how it works and I seem to do it wrong because `mixer.findChannel()` still picks reserved channels.

Here's my code:

```
        self.music1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
        self.music2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
        self.sound1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(2)
        self.sound2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(3)
        self.sound3 = pygame.mixer.Channel(4)
        self.sound4 = pygame.mixer.Channel(5)
        self.sound5 = pygame.mixer.Channel(6)
        self.sound6 = pygame.mixer.Channel(7)
        
        pygame.mixer.set_reserved(2)
```

I'd like to reserve music1 and music2.

The documentation states that the argument of `mixer.set_reserved()` defines the number of channels that will be reserved.

If I can't pick which channels will be reserved, is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed, there doesn't seem to be a way to determine which channels are reserved.  So is it *even possible* to use a reserved channel?

Comment: Printing out `str( self.music )`, gives some address output, e.g.: `<Channel object at 0x7fdfa46cbc18>`.  Printing out the result of `pygame.mixer.find_channel()` it gives an address *not already* assigned to a variable.  So just assigning it seems to (possibly) reserve it somehow.  Personally, I would just write your code without channel-reservation, and then worry about it when it's a problem.  Currently I see no way around this limitation in the API.

Comment: I created some issues on pygame's bugtracker, so the documentation will be corrected in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, pygame's documentation is lacking, and lot of stuff makes more sense if you look which SDL functions pygame actually calls and what those functions do.

So `mixer.set_reserved()` actually [calls](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/066a0bdeee461ab376aec52f5875623c1c36e86d/src_c/mixer.c#L1418) [`Mix_ReserveChannels`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_43.html#SEC43), but does not return the number of reserved channels:

> **Mix_ReserveChannels**
>
> *int Mix_ReserveChannels(int num)*
>
> Reserve num channels from being used when playing samples when passing in -1 as a channel number to playback functions. The channels are reserved starting from channel 0 to num-1. Passing in zero will unreserve all channels. Normally SDL_mixer starts without any channels reserved.
>
> The following functions are affected by this setting:
> 4.3.3 Mix_PlayChannel
> 4.3.4 Mix_PlayChannelTimed
> 4.3.5 Mix_FadeInChannel
> 4.3.6 Mix_FadeInChannelTimed

`mixer.findChannel()` [calls](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/066a0bdeee461ab376aec52f5875623c1c36e86d/src_c/mixer.c#L1451) [`Mix_GroupAvailable`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_47.html#SEC47):

> **Mix_GroupAvailable**
>
> *int Mix_GroupAvailable(int tag)*
>
> Find the first available (not playing) channel in group tag.

As you can see, `findChannel` ignores reserved channels. Reserving a channel only prevents it from being automatically picked when using one of the functions above. Pygame uses `Mix_PlayChannelTimed` and `Mix_FadeInChannelTimed`, for example [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/066a0bdeee461ab376aec52f5875623c1c36e86d/src_c/mixer.c#L668).

---

To sum up, if you want to make sure a sound is played, reserve one or more channels with `mixer.set_reserved`.

Then, to play that important sound, use `mixer.findChannel` to *either* get a reserved channel *or* to get an unreserved, free channel. You could also create a new `Channel` instance with a channel number of `0` (or more if you reserved more than one channel) if you want to have full control over with channel to play the sound.

Play all other sounds without specifying a channel, and they will play only on non-reserved channels.

So the code in your question already does what you want: reserving channel `0` and `1`.